# POST url enconding with cURL

Tags: post, curl, urlencode

when I have to send a POST request with CURL, in the POST fields if they contain strings with spaces do I have to url_encode the strings or the function will do it for me?

what's correct?

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS  => 'field=this%20is%20good'
```

or this

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS  => 'field=this is good'
```

I'm asking because I don't want it to encode the string twice and thus send incorrect data.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify that, but I suppose you're using PHP, right?

It must be urlencoded according to RFC 1738.
You can use the function http_build_query(). I use, for example:

```
$array = array('field' => 'this is good');
http_build_query($array, '', '&');
```

You could also simply pass $array as the option (like `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $array`), but this will create a multipart/form-data request, instead of the "normal" application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

PS: None of yours are correct, actually :) You should encode spaces with +, as per the RFC 1738, and not with %20.

Comment: I'm trying to imitate encodeURIComponent from js that apparently still uses %20 for spaces

Comment: There are 2 standards. RFC 3896 uses %20, while RFC 1738 recommends the +. If I'm not wrong, the "+" is used for historical reasons... Both ways should be fine, eventually. This is the same difference existing between urlencode() and rawurlencode()!